# SAPUI5: MERGE instead of POST after DELETE

Tags: odata, sapui5, crud

I'm testing a simple sample CRUD app. Everything works well...until I perform a DELETE (omodel.remove()) operation. If the next operation I do is an Insert (create entry, bind to view and submit changes) the app will perform MERGE (with the data of the deleted record) instead of POST and fail. Everything will work afterwards until I repeat this DELETE-INSERT sequence. If following the deletion, try to update an existing record, everything will work as well. Adding an omodel.refresh() at the beginning didn't work. Any ideas?

Starting with empty recordset, adding first record, model before submit changes
[image]

Record added, post performed
[image]

Ready to add 2nd record, all good in model, one existing and one new entry
[image]

2nd record added, another POST, all well
[image]

Ready to delete 1st record, situation right before the model.remove() operation, 2 recs, first one pending deletion
[image]

Record deleted, DELETE action triggered as expected
[image]

Last step, about to enter another record, see the existing and the pending new entry
[image]

BAMMM! Record NOT added, app instead of adding the new entry, performed a MERGE with the data of the deleted record!
[image]

Code for creating the new entry and passing it to the object page

```
        onActionAdd: function() {

        var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
        var oParamModel = this.getView().getModel("Params");
        oParamModel.setProperty("/ObjectMode", "Add");
        oModel.refresh();

        //var oNewObject = "{\"Curr\": \"GBP\"}";
        var oNewObject = "{\"Pernr\": \"1023912\",\"Begda\":\"" + new Date('2021', '05', '01').toString()
                          + "\",\"Endda\":\"" + new Date('2021', '06', '01').toString()
                          //+ "\",\"ActionDate\":\"" + new Date('2021', '07', '01').toString() 
                          + "\"}";
        oNewObject = JSON.parse(oNewObject);

        var oEntry = oModel.createEntry("/Industrial_ActionSet", {
            properties: oNewObject
        }); 

        oParamModel.setProperty("/EntryId", oEntry.sPath.toString());           
        this.getRouter().navTo("object", {
            objectId: oNewObject.Pernr,
            dateFromId: oNewObject.Begda,
            dateToId: oNewObject.Endda              
        });
    }
```

Code for save (insert/update)

```
        onActionSave: function() {

        var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
        var oParamModel = this.getView().getModel("Params");
        var objectMode = oParamModel.getProperty("/ObjectMode");            
        var self = this;

        // abort if the  model has not been changed 
        if (!oModel.hasPendingChanges()) {
            MessageBox.information(
                this.getResourceBundle().getText("noChangesMessage"), {
                    id: "noChangesInfoMessageBox",
                    styleClass: self.getOwnerComponent().getContentDensityClass()
                }
            );
            return;
        }   
        if (objectMode === "Add") {
            var sDateFrom = new Date(this.getView().byId("idDateFrom").getDateValue());
            var sObjectPath = oParamModel.getProperty("/EntryId") + "/Begda";
            oModel.setProperty(sObjectPath, sDateFrom);     
            var sDateTo = new Date(this.getView().byId("idDateTo").getDateValue());
            sObjectPath = oParamModel.getProperty("/EntryId") + "/Endda";
            oModel.setProperty(sObjectPath, sDateTo);                   
            var sActionDate = new Date(this.getView().byId("idActionDate").getDateValue());
            sObjectPath = oParamModel.getProperty("/EntryId") + "/ActionDate";
            oModel.setProperty(sObjectPath, sActionDate);
            var sMethod = "POST";
        } else {
            sMethod = "PUT";
        }

        oModel.submitChanges({
            method: sMethod,                
            success: function(oData, sResponse) {
                MessageToast.show("Record Updated");
                self.onNavBack();
            },
            error: function(oError) {
                jQuery.sap.log.error("Action Save oData Failure", oError);
            }
        });         
    },
```

Code for delete

```
        onActionDelete: function() {

        var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
        var msgText = this.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("confirmDelete");
        var sPath = this.getView().getBindingContext().sPath;
        var self = this;

        // Opens the confirmation dialog
        MessageBox.confirm(msgText, {
            title: "Exit Confirmation",
            initialFocus: sap.m.MessageBox.Action.CANCEL,
            onClose: function(sButton) {
                if (sButton === MessageBox.Action.OK) {
                    oModel.remove(sPath, {
                        method: "DELETE",
                        success: function(data) {
                            MessageToast.show("Record Deleted");
                            self.onNavBack();                               
                        },
                        error: function(e) {
                            jQuery.sap.log.error("Delete Action oData Failure", e);
                        }
                    });
                } else if (sButton === MessageBox.Action.CANCEL) {
                    MessageToast.show("Deletion aborted");
                    return;
                }
            }
        });         
    },
```

Thanks, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elaborate way to solve this but problem is related with dates as keys. There are 3 date fields in the entity, 2 of them keys. As soon as I converted the entity date keys to string (still DATS on the backend) everything started working fine...